# How do I convert an exe file into a runnable Mac file?

Tags: c++, macos, exe

My code is in c++ and was compiled in visual studio if that makes any difference. I also don’t have a Mac however I do have a friend that is willing to test my things on Mac.

Comment: C/C++ source code is often portable between compilers (e.g. MSVS and XCode).  The resulting executables are *NOT* portable between platforms.  So all you need to do is install a C++ compiler and your MacOS and try compiling.  It might work ... or it might not, depending on whether the source code itself is portable.  But you can't somehow "tweak" MSVS and get it to generate MacOS code on Windows, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: visual studio provides an option to build for mac, do use that to create a Mac executable , do check runtime environment https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Comment: @Meena Pintu: you're mistaken.  Visual Studio for windows *cannot* generate MacOS binaries.  And the (relatively new) [Visual Studio for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-relnotes) must be *installed* on a Mac.  C++ source code must be recompiled on a Mac in order to generate an executable for the Mac.

Comment: oh ,  In case ide doesn't directly provide this option on windows , then I think MSBUILD can be used or azure pipeline .  ( MSBUILD doesn't require ide to be installed to compile a vs code project .  thanks @paulsm

Comment: You might have some luck by installing WINE on the Mac:  https://www.winehq.org